# Pandas dataframe columns multiplication/division only when depends on another variable

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

In a pandas dataframe, currently I'm using a df.iterrows() approach but it is incredibly slow. I want to speed up the calculation of two columns using numpy or something similar, so probably a lambda function won't do the trick and it will be also slow. The problem is that it is a more-or-less complex logic, as the calculations depends on another variable ("inmarket") and I'm not sure if it can be done somehow.

Basically, what the code does is: There are 4 columns; "money", "shares", "Close" , "position" and also a couple of variables, "inmarket" and "numops".

Initially "inmarket" is 0. Initially "numops" variable is 0

The columns initially looks like:

```
money   shares   Close   position
100      0        10.1     0
  0      0        11.7     1
  0      0        13.8     0
  0      0        9.1      1
  0      0        11.2     0
  0      0        10.7     0
  0      0        11.3     0
```

And after the calculation they shoould look like:

```
money   shares   Close   position
100      0        10.1     0
0      9.9        11.7     1
136.62   0        13.8     0
0       15.01     9.1      1
168.11   0        11.2     0
168.11   0        10.7     0
168.11   0        11.3     0
```

and the numops variable = 4

The logic is:

If "inmarket" is 0 (so we can buy), each time that there is a 1 in the "position" column, the "money" is divided by "Close", the result is stored in the "Shares" column, and "money" goes to 0 (as we have bought the shares). We store somewhere a counter of the operation (like "numops" variable in my code example)

If "inmarket" is 1 (so we already have shares but no money), each time there is a 0, the "Shares" are multiplied by "Close", and then the result is put in "money", then "shares" go to 0. We store somewhere a counter of the operation

Here goes the code:

```
    self.df.loc[0, "money"] = self.start_money
    self.df.loc[0, "shares"] = 0
    numops=0
    inmarket = 0

    for i, row in self.df.iterrows():
        if not inmarket:
            if self.df.loc[i, "position"] == 1: #buy
            self.df.loc[i, "shares"] = self.df.loc[i-1, "money"] / self.df.loc[i, "Close"]     
            self.df.loc[i, "money"]=0
                inmarket=1
                numops+=1
            elif i: #we copy the previous row
                self.df.loc[i, "shares"] = self.df.loc[i-1, "shares"]
                self.df.loc[i, "money"] = self.df.loc[i-1, "money"]
        elif inmarket:
            if row["position"] == 0:#sell
                self.df.loc[i, "money"]=self.df.loc[i-1, "shares"] * self.df.loc[i, "Close"]
                self.df.loc[i, "shares"] = 0
                inmarket=0
                numops+=1
            elif i:
                self.df.loc[i, "shares"] = self.df.loc[i-1, "shares"]
                self.df.loc[i, "money"] = self.df.loc[i-1, "money"]
```